# Find subsequent records that aren't active

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table of DD information and I need to select from it any records that are Cancelled that don't have a subsequent Active record

I have tried

```
select 
    d1.DDIReference 
FROM DDI d1
LEFT OUTER JOIN DDI d2 ON (d1.DDIReference = d2.DDIReference AND d1.TransactionID < d2.TransactionID)
INNER JOIN [TM113 File for Jo to Check] tm on tm.[DDI Reference] = d1.DDIReference
WHERE 
    d1.DDStatus = 'CAN'
AND d2.DDStatus <> 'ACT'
```

but this will return me the DDIReference of a record that could be cancelled, cancelled, cancelled, active.

I only want to return records that are Cancelled with no Active.

Thanks

Darren

Comment: "but this will return me the DDIReference of a record that could be cancelled, cancelled, cancelled, active." - erm, what?

Comment: Provide some information about your schema.  That is kind of critical.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I am understanding your question correctly, but this query gets the cancelled records for which no active record with a higher `TransactionID` exists. Note that like your original query, if multiple records with status `CAN` exist, you will get one row in your results for each of those records. You could use `SELECT DISTINCT` to avoid that in this case.

```
SELECT d1.DDIReference 
FROM DDI d1
INNER JOIN [TM113 File for Jo to Check] tm on tm.[DDI Reference] = d1.DDIReference
WHERE d1.DDStatus = 'CAN'
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM DDI d2
    WHERE d2.DDIReference = d1.DDIReference
    AND d2.TransactionID > d1.TransactionID
    AND d2.DDStatus = 'ACT')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    d1.DDIReference 
FROM DDI d1
LEFT OUTER JOIN DDI d2 ON (d1.DDIReference = d2.DDIReference AND d1.TransactionID < d2.TransactionID)
INNER JOIN [TM113 File for Jo to Check] tm on tm.[DDI Reference] = d1.DDIReference
WHERE 
    d1.DDStatus = 'CAN'
AND d1.DDIReference  not in (select DDIReference from DDIReference  where DDStatus = 'ACT' )
```

Comment: Thanks for these 3 options.

Alexander Fedorenko, running your code only returns me 30 records.

HVD, your code returns me 297 records

sivareddy, your code returns 293 records.

The difference in the 4 records is that record 1: CAN,ACT,CAN record 2: ACT,CAN record 3: ACT,CAN record 4: ACT,CAN

So these are CAN with no subsequent (higher transactionID) ACT and i guess need to be included.

Thanks for everyones help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use option with OUTER [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) + [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) 1 operators

```
SELECT d1.DDIReference 
FROM DDI d1 INNER JOIN [TM113 File for Jo to Check] tm on tm.[DDI Reference] = d1.DDIReference
            OUTER APPLY (
                         SELECT TOP 1 d2.DDStatus
                         FROM DDI d2
                         WHERE d1.DDIReference = d2.DDIReference
                           AND d1.TransactionID < d2.TransactionID
                         ORDER BY d2.TransactionID DESC
                         ) o
WHERE d1.DDStatus = 'CAN' AND o.DDStatus <> 'ACT'
```